# jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery

```
/* EXCLUIR ARQUIVOS DA GALARIA */
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* EXCLUI ARQUIVOS DA GALERIA IMG E PDF */  
    $( "#btnexcluipdf" ).bind( "click", function() {

        var vID = $('#idarquivopdf').val();
        //alert(vID);

        //$("#status").html(
        //          "ID excluido: ");

        var vurl = '?pg=excluirarquivo';             
        var vData = {id:vID};       
        $.ajax(
            vurl 
            ,vData
            ,function(response,status){
                if(status == "sucess")
                {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

                    $("#status").html(
                    "ID excluido: " + obj.id );

                }   
            }
        );
    });
```

o php...

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

var_dump($_POST);
//$id = $_POST["id"];
?>

deixei o codigo assim.


/* EXCLUIR ARQUIVOS DA GALARIA */
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* EXCLUI ARQUIVOS DA GALERIA IMG E PDF */  
    $( "#btnexcluipdf" ).bind( "click", function() {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST"
            ,url: document.location.pathname + '?pg=excluirarquivo'
            ,data: { id: $('#idarquivopdf').val() }
            ,dataType: "html"           
        })
        .done(function( resposta ) {
            alert(resposta);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Erro:" + textStatus);
        }).always(function() {
            alert("OK");
        });



    });
```

ao clicar, o evento (alert(resposta);) mostra uma pagina html, depois ele passa pelo done e não mostra nada, mas chega ao final no OK.

Comment: Altere `bind` para `on` e `$.ahax` para `$.ajax`

Comment: Os parâmetros do AJAX devem está em JSON. Recomendo dar uma lida na [**documentação**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Aproveite também e leia [**.bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) que na versão **3.0** foi descontinuado, e para saber mais sobre [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: wmsouza , ja tinha ajustado, postei errado, mas mesmo assim não entra no ajax, consigo dar alert antes de depois mas não entra no ajax.

Comment: `$.ajax({ url: vurl, data: vData` ... Veja o link da documentação que o @ValdeirPsr passou!

Comment: `vurl` nao é um link valido, se está a enviar para a mesma pagina, use `var vurl = document.location.pathname + '?pg=excluirarquivo';`. O endereco tem de ter uma `path` válida.

Comment: balexandre, valeu pela dica, mas não sei o que ocorre, não consigo descobri pq não chega no php..

Comment: /* EXCLUIR ARQUIVOS DA GALARIA */
$(document).ready(function() {
  
 /* EXCLUI ARQUIVOS DA GALERIA IMG E PDF */ 
 $( "#btnexcluipdf" ).bind( "click", function() {
  
  $.ajax({
   method: "POST"
   ,url: document.location.pathname + '?pg=excluirarquivo'
   ,data: { id: $('#idarquivopdf').val() }
   ,dataType: "html"   
  })
  .done(function( resposta ) {
   alert(resposta);
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   alert("Erro:" + textStatus);
  }).always(function() {
   alert("OK");
  });
  
  
  
 });

Comment: <?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

var_dump($_POST);
//$id = $_POST["id"];